# PHP/MYSQL Newsletter read/unread system

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, relationship

i have a small problem.

1. Table (user_table)

   id | username | name | password
2. Table (newsletter)

   id | date
3. Table (newsletter_posts) <-- This table isn't very important for my problem.

The user_table is flexible, that means, sometimes i create new users, sometimes i delete users.

The newsletter table is also flexible.

This month

```
1 | 12345678
```

Next month

```
2 | 23456789
```

and so on...

But how can i create a read/unread table for all newsletter and all users. I have around 100 users and 12 newsletter per year.

Greetings

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a table that relates the newsletter table to the user table.

```
newsletter_user
----------------
id
user_id
newsletter_id
created_date
```

Existence of a row should occur (insert) when a user reads a newsletter.  If there is no row, the user hasn't read the newsletter.  Create a unique index on user_id,newsletter_id.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had the same idea but, when i have around 100 users and 12 newsletter per year i have in 3 years 3600 rows...

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem.  Relational databases are designed to efficiently handle long/thin tables like this.  3600 rows is absolutely nothing to a relational database, especially when you simply need to find the presence of one specific row.  FYI my experience includes working with millions of users.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a table that has

```
user id | newsletter id | status
```

Then you can query a newsletter to see who has read it or a user to see what newsletters they have read

If you want you can also add in some date fields, say for date read if you want to track that data.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a mapping table. You can name it **newsletter_users_log**. It can have columns like:

1. id -> BIGINT auto increment
2. newsletter_id -> foreign key to newsletter table
3. user_id -> foreign key to users table
4. date_sent -> DateTime